# Canvas module compilation osx error

Tags: macos, node.js, canvas, npm, homebrew

I'm trying to install captcha npm module, which exploits the canvas module.

Unfortunately I have problem to install that module on OSX. 
I'm getting the following error:

```
> canvas@1.0.4 install ....../node_modules/canvas
> node-gyp rebuild

not found: ldconfig
gyp: Call to './util/has_lib.sh jpeg' returned exit status 0. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.21/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:424:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.21/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd ...../node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.21
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! weird error 1
```

Any idea? Apparently there is ldconfig missing. But no idea how to install it.

I'm using homebrew, and I have the lastest XCode, and command line tools installed.

Answer (score 5):

This is my workaround:

First we need to install cairo:

```
brew install cairo jpeg
```

It takes sometime. However now it's time to update  PKG_CONFIG_PATH, pointing at the cairo libraries.

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/X11/lib/pkgconfig
```

To compile canvas we need to have node-gyp installed.

```
npm install node-gyp -g
```

If the installation still is not working because of missing jpeg lib, you need to run:

```
npm install canvas
```

in directory of the project where it's needed and then to stop installation just before the error reporting. Then you need change directory and recompile manually the C++ binding

```
cd node_modules/canvas/
node-gyp rebuild
```

after that you should have working canvas module.

Answer (score 0):

M1 native does not release binary version of canvas in node15. Therefore, when you install canvas, you will automatically compile from the source code, but if you do not install the corresponding dependency, you will report an error.

Solution

`arch -arm64 brew install pkg-config cairo pango jpeg giflib librsvg`

Answer (score -1):

According to my knowledge you need to install Get Xcode 6.1 .

Install Xcode and the Xcode Command Line Tools

Agree to Xcode license in Terminal: `sudo xcodebuild -license`

Install MacPorts for your version of OS X:
OS X 10.10 Yosemite

https://www.macports.org/install.php